# How to force clipping (not scaling) when printing TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a PDF being outputted as a Letter size using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org). I have an image that covers the background and displays correctly when viewing the PDF, however when I go to print the PDF it adds about a half inch border for my printer's margins. This also scales down the whole content of my PDF, but is most noticeable on the background image.

I'd like it to not scale my content when I print, but to use the exact 8.5x11" size of my PDF as-is and just clip the edges as needed for my printer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found that works is to set the PrintScaling property to "None", using `setViewerPreferences`

```
$pdf->setViewerPreferences( array("PrintScaling"=>"None") );
```

[TCPDF Docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ad09b32089f8e68c9d8424a2777627c21)